# Can i automatically set the margins for my subplots?

Tags: matplotlib, margin, subplot

The margins of my plots are unfortunatly too small for the Text i want to set there, 45* rotated:

[image]

How can i prevent the Labels for the datapoints from overlapping into the title? Would be best if it were computed, so i don"t have to manually adjust it.
How can i remove all the whitespace around the graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an up to date matplotlib version, you can try using [Tight Layout](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/tight_layout_guide.html). Otherwise you will have to do it by hand with `subplots_adjust`.